# JFugue: Is there a way to get the current note that a player() is on?

Tags: java, jfugue

I am making a virtual piano project and I have some transcribed sample songs. I would like to know if I could get the current note that the player is on, so that it could be displayed visually on a piano.

Edit: I'm still learning Java, so sorry in advance if I need some more explanation than usual.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you check any of the examples on the jfugue website or any tutorials?

Comment: I've tried reading up on parser but nothing seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: JFugue knows about notes as it is *parsing* the MusicString, but once the notes are *playing*, that's all handled by javax.sound.midi.Sequencer playing a Sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a ParserListener to listen for any musical event that any parser is parsing. I have adjusted one of the examples to print out the note position in an octave. You can modify this to find out exactly which note is pressed:

```
public class ParserDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidMidiDataException, IOException {
        MidiParser parser = new MidiParser(); // Remember, you can use any Parser!
        MyParserListener listener = new MyParserListener();
        parser.addParserListener(listener);
        parser.parse(MidiSystem.getSequence(new File(PUT A MIDI FILE HERE)));
    }
}

//Extend the ParserListenerAdapter and override the onNoteParsed event to find the current note
class MyParserListener extends ParserListenerAdapter {    
    @Override
    public void onNoteParsed(Note note) {
        //A "C" note is in the 0th position of an octave
        System.out.println("Note pushed at position " + note.getPositionInOctave());
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.jfugue.org/examples.html

Comment: Note that you could also use `note.getToneString() `, see other methods you can use to get details about a note here: http://www.jfugue.org/doc/org/jfugue/theory/Note.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this solution out!

Answer (score 1):

When JFugue is playing music, it is using `javax.sound.midi.Sequencer` to playback a MIDI `Sequence`. That means you can listen to the MIDI events themselves using a `Receiver` on the same `MidiDevice`, and since MIDI is a system-wide resource on your computer, you can even do this outside of Java.

Comment: I've been doing some research but so far I'm having trouble understanding some of the code. How would I use a receiver to get the MIDI events from the RealtimePlayer I am using? Thanks.

Comment: See this post, which has an answer with a code sample. In particular, note the send() method. Within that message, you can pick apart the MIDI event to find out whether it's a Note On, Note Off (and in those cases, which notes), or other event. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013510/receive-midi-input-with-javax-sound-midi